# Is Indy's line about Pancho Villa a reference to The Young Indiana Jones Chronicles?

Tags: indiana-jones, the-kingdom-of-the-crystal-skull, young-indiana-jones

In *Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull*, Indy tells Mutt that he learned to speak Quechua from Pancho Villa's forces. I remember that he had an adventure with Pancho Villa in *The Young Indiana Jones Chronicles*. Is this a reference to this adventure? If so, which episode was it?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20070724014822/http://www.indianajones.com/marshall/character/indianajones/

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2159/49).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it ***most likely is*** a reference to the *Young Indiana Jones Chronicles*. The specific adventure with Pancho Villa was shown in the first episode, the pilot ***"Young Indiana Jones and the Curse of the Jackal".*** It was also recut as the 6th film, [***Spring Break Adventure***](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Spring_Break_Adventure).

Lucasfilms considers most things in canon, with the feature films being the highest canon, and the tv shows as a lower canon. Conflicts between the two are handled by the higher canon being right. This is called [Indycron](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indycron), similar to the old Lucasfilms canon structure for Star Wars (before Disney changed everything). So events in *The Young Indiana Jones Chronicles* are canon to *Kingdom*, unless the film said otherwise. In this case, it directly references the events.

*The Young Indiana Jones Chronicles* of course, was produced by George Lucas, and Harrison Ford was even in an episode. [The Crystal Skulls were even going to be used by Lucas in the the *Young Indiana Jones Chronicles* before the show was canceled.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Kingdom_of_the_Crystal_Skull#Development) One of the writers for Crystal Skull, Frank Darabont, also wrote for the tv show.

Answer (score 7):

The old [Indianajones.com website](http://web.archive.org/web/20070724014822/http://www.indianajones.com/marshall/character/indianajones/) (produced and managed by LucasFilm) featured an extensive fictional biography of Indy. This article included a wealth of information taken directly from the Young Indiana Jones Chronicles, including this snippet:

> *In the years following Anna's death, Henry Jones became consumed by
>   his research regarding the Holy Grail. This served to distance him
>   from his young son. In 1916, during a visit to extended family in New
>   Mexico, Indy escaped his father's reach. **A trip across the Mexican
>   border swept Indy up in the Mexican revolution, and Indy briefly rode
>   with General Francisco Villa.***

Since, according to LucasFilm the Young Indiana Jones Chronicles exist within the [same canon universe](http://web.archive.org/web/20080603083220/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261663&tstart=0) as the films, there's absolutely no good reason to assume that the film shouldn't directly reference the [pilot for the TV series](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Indiana_Jones_and_the_Curse_of_the_Jackal); Young Indiana Jones and the Curse of the Jackal.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Indiana_Jones_Chronicles#Plot):

> The series is also referenced in Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the
>   Crystal Skull, when Indy describes his adventures with Pancho Villa
>   (chronicled in the first episode) to Mutt Williams.

The first episode of the series was [Young Indiana Jones and the Curse of the Jackal](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0394998/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl):

> Indiana finally caught up again with this jackal shaped artifact in
>   1916, after getting himself involved in the Mexican revolution while
>   crossing the border with his cousin Frank. Having joined up with
>   Pancho Villa, Indy became fast friends with Remy Baudouin, another
>   revolutionary who originally hails from Belgium.